# Unable to ping from local os(operating system) to virtual machine(vm ware) os( both on a same machine).

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, ping

I am unable to ping from my windows 7 to virtual machine (ubuntu 14) which is installed on the same system or vice versa. But form other system i am able to ping and everything is working fine. What should i configure so that it will ping to vm.

Comment: It is unclear from your post what can ping and what not (see discussion below edvinas.me's answer). Could you make a table to show what *does* ping and what does not?

Comment: I am just unable to ping from local os to vm os both on the same machine and also in reverse . from local os to other everything is fine and from vm os to other everything is fine. i have istalled zenoss in vm and trying to ping. for testing i am able to access zenoss and can ping to zenoss from other machines in the network

Answer (score 2):

Your Virtual Machine is likely using NAT Networking. You need to setup either a private network or Bridge network type for your Virtual Machine. This will be done in your Virtual Machine settings in VMWare.

You can find information on configuring network bridge for VMWare in https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_changing_bridged_windows.html

Comment: As I understand it he says he is unable to ping from his host OS to the guest, but it works for other hosts pinging the guest. In NAT networking one would expect the opposite.

Comment: Well I am not sure about VMWare, but VirtualBox NAT acts exactly like @ali786 suggested. It let's a VM ping Host, but not the opposite.

Comment: I am already using a Bridge Network. and i am able to ping to other pc's that are in my network.

Comment: Is there a firewall on the OS by any change which blocks ICMP requests? Are you using the right IP? What are you trying to accomplish (besides ping)?

Comment: No , I am just unable to ping from local os to vm os both on the same machine and also in reverse . from local os to other everything is fine and from vm os to other everything is fine.